# wamp windows xp httpd.exe aestan tray menu

Tags: windows-xp, wampserver, windows-xp-sp3

I'm having problems getting WAMPSERVER to run. Let's start with what I do know:

1) I have **32bit** windows xp running with a athalon X2 340 Dual. The property menu of my computer says: (the lack of x64 means I'm running 32bits.)

> *System: Microsoft XP  Professional Version 2002 Service Package 3*

2) I have .NET 4.0, C++ 2008 Redist..., and C++ 2010 Redist... installed (each 32bit).

3) I have tried to install both WAMPSERVER2.5 and WAMPSERVER2.2e. Both give me these errors:

> *httpd.exe is not a valid win32 application* and 
>   *Aestan Tray Menu has encountered a problem and needs to close.*

The 2.2e version also gives:

> *mysql.exe is not a valid win32 application*

I realize this problem goes back to 2011. I appreciate your patience with it. I have been all over the forums on this one. Nothing seems to work.

I did see this on another form:

> The VC11 library (C++ 2012 Redist..) will not run on Windows XP, even
>   SP3 or Windows Server 2003, so the minimum system requirements to run
>   WAMPServer 2.5 are: Windows 7 SP1 , Windows 8/8.1 , Windows Vista SP2
>   , Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 , Windows Server 2012/R2.

All help is appreciated. Please keep it constructive guys. Any Ideas? Do you see something I'm doing wrong? Any advanced troubleshooting ideas/ tutorials? workarounds? Thanks! :)

Comment: So I had two issues. 1) I had .NET 4.0 installed. I needed .NET 3.5. I was also trying to install x64 bit Wampserver 2.2. Wampsever2.5  still doesn't work on Windows XP in my experience. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: WampServer 2.5 does not run on Windows XP or Server 2003, as the message you posted explains. This is because APache/PHP and MySQL require the VC11 runtime library and that library will not run of either of those old OS's. Its not a WAMPServer issue its a obsolesence issue.

Answer (score 2):

The VC11 library will not run on Windows XP, even SP3 or Windows Server 2003, so the minimum system requirements to run WAMPServer 2.5 are:
Windows 7 SP1 ,
Windows 8/8.1 ,
Windows Vista SP2 ,
Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 ,
Windows Server 2012/R2.

---

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123685